# What does the RTM in MVC 3 RTM standfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I found the mvc 3 rtm project on codeplex.  What does RTM stand for? And is this source code suppose to match what is used by MVC 3 today?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stands for "Release to Market".  I beleive its the Final Stage when you got from CTP, to Beta, to RTM.  CTP is Community Tech Preview (limited release to Techs that care and will give feedback.)

Comment: Usually RTM stands for Release to Manufacturer! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#RTM_or_RTW

Answer (score 4):

Release to Manufacturing. Yes.

Comment: That's what it stands for, yes. What that *means* in this age of digital content distribution isn't all that clear though.